# Issue with sending emails JAX-RS

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs, jakarta-mail

I've been recently working on building a web forget password feature, by using an email with an html content. However, when I tried to test it, I kept getting the server internal error, code 500. What could be the issue? The code for the Emailer can be found below, together with the dependency. I am currently running my JAX-RS project using a Tomcat application server.

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class EmailSender {
    private static final Properties EmailConfig = new Properties();

    public static void sendEmail(String toEmailAddress,String emailSubject){
        final String username = "";
        final String password = "";
        EmailConfig.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        EmailConfig.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
        EmailConfig.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        EmailConfig.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(EmailConfig,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
                    }
                });
        try{
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmailAddress));
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("******@gmail.com"));
            msg.setSubject(emailSubject);
            String content ="<html><body><a href='recoverpage.html'></a>Click on this link to reset your password</body></html>";
            msg.setContent(content,"text/html");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to send email because " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: 500 can mean anything. You need to try and get a stack trace.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha the method apparently throws an exception, classNotFoundException. How could I solve it? It points to the EmailSender class.